# Sunspot Gem Using in STI TABLE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

i have `Account` Model,`Asset`, `Capital` and `Revenue` this table are all inherited in my `Account` model. i have 3 kind of attributes in my Account model. name, code and type. when i create an account where will be to insert will happen one in my account and the other one is in my type for example

```
Account.create(name: "test123", code:"test123", type:"Asset")
```

sql will run Two Insert one for Account model and one for Asset Table

and my sunspot work well it will **reindex** my database and i can search my params

but when i update my model Account my sql run one insert and one update

my question is how can i reindex my model when i update. with a particular data. i can do `Sunspot.reindex` but this is will load all data in my sql. that will cause me to slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i put this to my model

```
 after_update do
  Sunspot.index Account.where(id: self.id)
end
```

Comment: regarding indexing, its handled properly automatically by `sunspot`. only thing you are advised to do manually is "Commit".

Comment: commit are for add , delete and edit my only problem is to edit

Comment: its weird why i got a problem in editing when i use STI but its ok now

Answer (score 4):

> sql will run Two Insert one for Account model and one for Asset Table

FYI you use STI when you want to share same database table between multiple models because they are similar in attributes and behavior. Like `AdminUser` model is likely to have almost same attributes/columns as `PublisherUser` or `ReaderUser`. Therefore you might wish to have a common table called `users` or model `User` and share this table among the above mentioned models.

**Point** is: ActiveRecord will run a single SQL query not two, like:

```
INSERT INTO "accounts" ("name", "code", "type") VALUES ('test123', 'test123', 'Asset')
```

---

> my question is how can i reindex my model when i update. with a particular data. i can do Sunspot.reindex but this is will load all data in my sql. that will cause me to slow

Actually `sunspot_rails` is designed to auto-reindex whenever you make changes to your model/record. It listens to the `save` [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks).

But you need to make sure that you are not using methods like `update_column(s)`. [See the list of silent create/update methods which do not trigger callbacks and validations at all](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord#cheat-sheet).

---

In addition, you need to understand the concept of `batch size` in terms of Solr. For performance reasons, all of your new indexes are not immediately committed. **Committed** means, writing indexes to database like in RDBMS commits.

By default the `batch_size` for commits is **50**. Meaning after 50 `index` method executions only the indexes will be committed and you will be able to search the records. To change it, use following

```
# in config/initializers/sunspot_config.rb
Sunspot.config.indexing.default_batch_size = 1 # or any number
```

or

```
# in models; its not considered good though
after_commit do
  Sunspot.commit
end
```

---

For manual re-indexing, you can use like [@Kathryn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44564909/3437900) suggested.

But, I don't think you need to intervene in the auto-operation. I think you were not seeing immediate results so you were worrying.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#reindexing-objects), objects will be indexed automatically if you are on Rails. But it also mentions you can reindex a class manually:

```
Account.reindex
Sunspot.commit
```

It also suggests using `Sunspot.index` on individual objects.